# TensorFlow - Difference between tf.keras.layers.Layer vs tf.keras.Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Reading through the [documentation of implementing custom layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_layers) with `tf.keras`, they specify two options to inherit from, `tf.keras.Layer` and `tf.keras.Model`.

Under the context of *creating custom layers*, I'm asking myself what is the difference between these two? Technically what is different?

If I were to implement the transformer encoder for example, which one would be more suitable? (assuming the transformer is a only a "layer" in my full model)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the documentation:

> The Model class has the same API as Layer, with the following
>   differences: - It exposes built-in training, evaluation, and
>   prediction loops (model.fit(), model.evaluate(), model.predict()). -
>   It exposes the list of its inner layers, via the model.layers
>   property. - It exposes saving and serialization APIs.
>
> Effectively, the "Layer" class corresponds to what we refer to in the
>   literature as a "layer" (as in "convolution layer" or "recurrent
>   layer") or as a "block" (as in "ResNet block" or "Inception block").
>
> Meanwhile, the "Model" class corresponds to what is referred to in the
>   literature as a "model" (as in "deep learning model") or as a
>   "network" (as in "deep neural network").

So if you want to be able to call `.fit()`, `.evaluate()`, or `.predict()` on those blocks or you want to be able to save and load those blocks separately or something you should use the Model class. The Layer class is leaner so you won't bloat the layers with unnecessary functionality...but I would guess that that generally wouldn't be a big problem.

Answer (score 1):

- A layer takes in a tensor and give out a tensor which is a result of
  some tensor operations
- A model is a composition of multiple layers.

If you are building a new model architecture using existing keras/tf layers then build a custom model.

If you are implementing your own custom tensor operations with in a layer, then build a custom layer. If you are using non tensor operation inside your custom layer, then you have to code how the layer will forward propagate and backward propagate.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't see the difference. Doesn't the second point also takes in a tensor and give out a tensor which is a result of some tensor operations...? What about implementing the transformer encoder - if it is only a part of a model (not all of it) should it be a `Model` or a `Layer`?

Comment: Let say you have a series of images (say frames of a video) and you want to use a CNN to extract features then  fed these to LSTM frame by frame and finally make a prediction (say type of video) you will build a custom model. Now let say you want to a mechanism to add random noise to the learned weights during forward prop then you will  build a customer layer. The transformer encoder if I understand correctly from the papers is not a layer but it a custom model which uses only attention.

Comment: Okay, so given that *in my specific scenario* I'm using the transformer, or wavenet or any other already designed block, and it is only a PART of my model, should it be a layer or a model inside my model? And why? What is the technical difference ?