# Loading customized model in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I defined a sequential model that includes a **CustomerLayer** with an attribute **CustomerLayer.k**. I noticed that when **CustomeLayer** defined as **tf.keras.layers.Layer** (i.e., `class CustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer)`), the model is able to be reloaded. However, if I change it to **tf.keras.Model** (i.e., `class CustomLayer(tf.keras.Model)`), the reloaded model does not contain **CustomerLayer.k**. Can someone explain why I cannot define CustomerLayer as tf.keras.Model. In my understanding based on this post ([TensorFlow - Difference between tf.keras.layers.Layer vs tf.keras.Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55109696/tensorflow-difference-between-tf-keras-layers-layer-vs-tf-keras-model)), the difference between these two classes is that the tf.keras.Model contains  `.fit()`, `.evaluate()`, or `.predict()`. Is there any other difference between them? TIA

**Code:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


class CustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
# class CustomLayer(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, k, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.k = k
        self.lin1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.k, name='custom_sublayer1')

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update({"k": self.k})
        return config

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config: dict):
        return cls(**config)

    def call(self, input):
        return self.lin1(input)


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.Input(name='input_layer', shape=(10,)),
    CustomLayer(5, name='custom_layer'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, name='dense_layer1'),
])

x = np.random.rand(1, 10)
output = model(x)
model.save('ckpts/sandbox_model')

new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('ckpts/sandbox_model', custom_objects={'CustomLayer':CustomLayer, 'CustomSublayer': CustomSublayer})
output_new_model = new_model(x)
print(new_model.summary())
```

I tried this link ([TensorFlow - Difference between tf.keras.layers.Layer vs tf.keras.Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55109696/tensorflow-difference-between-tf-keras-layers-layer-vs-tf-keras-model)). But it doesn't explain why the tf.keras.model doesn't work in my case.